# Como salvar uma imagem no cache da aplicação e exibir depois?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Fui designado a antes de iniciar a aplicação exibir imagens promocionais.
As imagens são obtidas através de JSON, que também possui uma configuração de tempo de visualização.

Estou usando o seguinte código para armazenar a imagem vinda de uma URL no diretório /Library/Caches/Images/:

```
// /Library/Caches
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSLocalDomainMask, YES);
// /Library/Caches/Images
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images"];

NSString *extension = [imageURLString pathExtension];
// /Library/Caches/Images/image_0.jpg
NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d.%@", index, extension]];
NSData *file = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString]];
[file writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
[self.imagesCache addObject:filePath];
```

Depois para exibir as imagens estou usando o código:

```
// Dentro de um loop. current é o índice do loop
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self.imagesCache objectAtIndex:current]];
self.currentImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

Quando eu pego a imagem diretamente da URL funciona, mas do cache não.

```
self.currentImage = [[UIImageView alloc]
                 initWithImage:[UIImage
                                imageWithData:[NSData
                                               dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString]]]];
```

Quem poderia me dar uma luz sobre esse processo de cache de imagens?
Não dá erro mas as imagens ficam todas pretas quando obtidas do cache.

Comment: Você conferiu se realmente o método `writeToFile:atomically:` está retornando *YES*? Pode ser que nem esteja salvando a imagem.

Comment: Este link talvez  possa esclarecer sua dúvida.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784278/how-to-cache-images-in-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você criou o diretório em que está tentando salvar?

Código para criação:

```
-(void)createDirectory:(NSString *)directoryName atFilePath:(NSString *)filePath
{
    NSString *filePathAndDirectory = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:directoryName];
    NSError *error;

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePathAndDirectory
                                   withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                                    attributes:nil
                                                         error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Create directory error: %@", error);
    }
}
```

Também encontrei este [tutorial](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/13315-image-caching-tutorial.html) que é bem explicativo.